# Which one is correct to use,I or me?

Tags: grammar

He is taller than I. →correct
He is taller than me. →incorrect

Is it possible to use object me?
They use object with another case.

I am taller than him.(object)

Answer (score 1):

"I" and "me" are both correct.

Using "He is" (instead of the contraction "He's") makes this statement sound more formal. In such cases, "He is taller than I" or "He is taller than I am" sounds slightly better since using "I" also sounds slightly more formal.

"He's taller than me" sounds more natural in ordinary speech though and since you won't normally state that someone is taller than yourself in a formal context, "me" would be my preferred word.